# How to save the symbols that got stripped from an object file?

Tags: linux, strip

```
strip command objectfile -o objectfile_stripped
```

saves the stripped objectfile in objectfile_stripped.

How do I save the symbols and debug information that got stripped onto a file? Strip command throws away the symbols and debug but I'd like to save these into a file.

Comment: The information is saved in the original object file. Using `-o` means the objectfile is not modified.

Comment: How do I save the stripped symbols into a file? The strip command throws away the stripped symbols and outputs the reduced binary. I'd like to save the removed symbols and debug info onto a file.

Comment: It doesn't throw them away when you use the `-o` option. That leaves `objectfile` unchanged, and puts the stripped version in `objectfile_stripped`. So the symbols are saved in `objectfile`.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. But can I just have the symbols alone in a file? I don't want to have the entire object file, although it also includes the symbols, for size reasons.  Thanks